# validate at least one in has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a model with:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

How do I validate that the model has at least one user in the model?  I tried:

```
validates_presence_of :users
```

But that doesn't seem to give me what I want...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would write custom validation:

```
validate :has_users?

def has_users?
  # rails 2:
  errors.add_to_base "Model must have some users." if self.users.blank?
end
```

That would do exactly that.

Note in rails 3+ you have to use:

```
  # rails 3+
  errors.add :base, "Model must have some users." if self.users.blank?
```

In rails 4+ there's a built-in shortcut, so you can simply do:

```
validates :users, presence: true
```

Comment: I needed to use `self.errors.add :base, "Model must have some users." `

Comment: This will brake the has_and_belongs_to_many relation

if you do:

`your_related_model.users.build(name: "Test")`
`your_related_model.save`

you will get the error  "Model must have some users."

This is not correct

Answer (score 33):

In rails 4 you can just do

```
validates :users, presence: true
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3.2.x:

```
validate :has_users?

def has_users?
  errors.add(:base, 'Error message') if self.users.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Josh Susser wrote a [plugin](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/7/14/validate-your-existence) that adds a `validates_existence_of` method that does what you want. It ensures that a foreign key references a record that exists.

Comment: That looked promising, but it didn't work:
"Cannot validate existence of :users because it is not a belongs_to association."  Looks like it's only for belongs_to...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
validates :users, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
```