# How can I make sure my has_many will have a size of at least 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

```
A has_many B

validates :b, ? #
```

How exactly I could check that I have at least 2 B?

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3? Try:

```
validates :b, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950008/validate-at-least-one-in-has-and-belongs-to-many/952043#952043) you should be able to do :

```
validate :has_at_least_two_potatoes?

def has_at_least_two_potatoes?
  errors.add_to_base "Model must have at least 2 potatoes" if self.potatoes.size < 2
end
```