# At least one text_field must be filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, textfield

I have 3 `text_fields` in my view in which I enter students name. Of course you can enter one student or three students but I want to make sure that at least one student was provided because a project must have a student assigned to it.

Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for @project, url: projects_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.fields_for :students do |s| %>
            <%= s.label :name %>
            <%= s.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

And `new` method from Projects controller:

```
  def new
    @project = Project.new()
    3.times do 
      student = @project.students.build
    end
  end
```

What I want to achieve is to check if at least one student was provided and if not just show alert or disable submiting.

### Edit

Models used in this project:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
  validate :validate_student_count

  def validate_student_count
    errors.add(:students, "at least one is required") if students.count < 1
  end
end
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what you are having issues with, only what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a custom validation rule as:

```
  validate :validate_student_count

  def validate_student_count
    errors.add(:students, "at least one is required") if students.count < 1
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of very similar questions on the internet. Here's some examples: [Validate the number of has_many items in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836897/validate-the-number-of-has-many-items-in-ruby-on-rails) and [Validate that an object has one or more associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535012/rails-validate-that-object-has-one-or-more-associated-objects-has-many-relati)