# How to validate uniqueness of two new records for nested has many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model Person which can have many Cars and i want to create a nested form to create two records of car at once for which i am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Allow to create two car records at once:

1. Hatchback
2. Sedan

A person with can leave the one or both of the car fields to be blank and i am using `allow_blank` to handle that.

Models:

```
#### Model: Car
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  validates :registration_number, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true,
              format: {with: SOME_REGEX}

  validate :both_cars_registration_cant_be_same

  def both_cars_registration_cant_be_same
    car1 = registration_number if type == 'hatchback'
    car2 = registration_number if type == 'sedan'
    if car1 == car2
      errors.add(:registration_number, "Both number can't be same")
    end
  end 

### Model : Person   
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars, allow_destroy: true, 
           reject_if:  proc { |attr| attr['registration_number'].blank?  }
```

Controller:

```
### Controller : Person

class PersonsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @person = Person.new
    2.times { @person.cars.build }
  end
```

Below is the small snippet of form partial

```
...
...
### _form.html.erb ###
<%= f.fields_for :cars do |car|
   <%= render 'car_form', c: car %>
<% end %>
...
...

### _car_form.html.erb  ###
<% if c.index == 0 %>
  <p>Type: Sedan</p>
  <%= c.hidden_field :type, value: "sedan" %>
<% else %>
  <p>Type: Hatchback</p>
  <%= c.hidden_field :type, value: "hatchback" %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <%= c.label :registration_number %>
  <%= c.text_field :registration_number %>
</div>
```

I can use `validate :both_cars_registration_cant_be_same` with `valid?` from Cars model in rails console but how do i run this validation from the parent model (person) so that i get the error message when the form is submitted with same registration number for two cars?. I want to validate that the registration number fields entered for two record must be different and not same. Also let me know if my form helper where i am using `index` on the `fields_for` object is the correct way to do it?

P.S : Using rails 4

Comment: Remember `type` can only have one value per model instance in your validation. If `type` is neither `hatchback` nor `sedan` then the equality condition will be `nil == nil` which is `true`. In fact, it only appears to evaluate false if `type` is either `"hatchback"` or `"sedan"` AND `registration_number` is NOT `nil`. Perhaps this is what you want, but probably not, and either way there's some really confusing logic at play. I'd consider refactoring the validation logic to make it more clear.

Comment: yes i know i can fall into that trap, I will definately fix that but first i wanted to validate that both the registration number when entered (not nil) should be unique (not same). I wan't to catch that error first.

Answer (score 0):

Move cars validation to Person model. This question could be helpful for you: [Validate that an object has one or more associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535012/rails-validate-that-object-has-one-or-more-associated-objects-has-many-relati)

Comment: I want to validate that the registration number fields entered for two record must be different and not same while create. If no fields are entered i will not validate. I am not sure how the above solution handles it?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
belongs_to :project


validates_uniqueness_of :title, allow_blank: false, conditions: -> {where(parent_id: nil)}, scope: :project
```

use the scope validation option
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: can you explain a bit about the "conditions:"?

Comment: condition will run this validation only on collection members that meet the condition. so in this case, this is a folder, that has parent folders. so the condition is to validate uniqueness of folder titles with no parents, scoped under the project. so i can't have project1 with folder1 folder1, but i can have projcet1 with folder1 and project2 with folder1 - reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I don't get any error message in this. Does it really work ?

Comment: Does it work for new records? . I don't know if the conditions of nil parent_id works. ?