# ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy HABTM create/build not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models. Two are related through a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with the appropriate join table and one with an `has_many` association.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :colors
end

class Color < ActivRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end
```

I can create new items with a color in the following way:

```
@item = Item.new(name: "ball")
@item.users << @user
@item.save

@item.colors.create!(name: "blue")
```

The item is now linked to the user referenced by `@user`.

But I think there has to be another way to create items for users, like the way I added the color.

```
@user.item.create!(name: "car")
```

This doesn't work because the users-array of the created item is empty and the item does now not belong to a user.

What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: you not create new item ,  just build `@item = Item.new(name: "ball")` to `@item = Item.create(name: "ball")`

Comment: I don't think so. `@item = Item.new` + `@item.save` is like `Item.create`. But that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has_and_belongs_to_many should not be used. ( [github )](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/6be94d292760...781390551b4a)

Instead, use a has_many with the through flag: [guides.rubyonrails.org...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Something like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items
  has_many :users, through: :user_items # I can never think of a good name here

  has_many :colors
  has_many :item_colors, through: :colors
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_colors
  has_many :items, through: :item_colors
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items
  has_many :items, through: :user_items
end

class ItemColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :color
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

It may seem complicated, but it will solve your problems.  Also, consider the situation where many items share the same color, if there isn't a join table there, it would be more difficult to categorize items by color.

Comment: I've tried that and I will try it again, but I don't like it to have an extra model only for the association.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works now. But how can I prevent the creation of items that are not assigned to a user? I put `validates :users, presence: true` in the item model, but that's not working.

Comment: Ok, thanks this answers solves one of my problems. I will write another questions with the other problem.

Comment: I believe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950008/validate-at-least-one-in-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: The extra model will really free you up.  What if you want a user to be able to have more than one of a specific item.  A quantity count would fit right into the UserItem.

Comment: I tried that validation method, but it does not work. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951063/has-many-through-create-validate-presence