# has-many-through create! validate presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, has-many-through

I have two models `User` and `Item` which are related with a `has_many through` association. I want to create users without items, but item creation should validate the presence of at least one user. I create items in the following way:

```
@user.items.create!(name: "Ball")
```

What can I do to create a working validation of the presence of a user before creating the item?

I tried the following approaches:

- a `validate :users, presence: true` in the `Item` model
- a `validate :item_users, presence: true` in the `Item` model
- a `validate :user, :item, presence: true` in the `ItemUser` join model
- a `validate :should_have_at_least_one_user` in the `Item` model with a private function that does `error.add(:base, 'select at least one user') if self.users.count < 1`

None of these approaches had worked. I think the problem is some kind of race condition, because when I create items the following way, some of the validations did work.

```
@item.new(name: "Ball")
@item.users << @user
@item.save
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback

In your Item controller:

```
before_save :user_for_item_exists?


private
def user_for_item_exists?
  return nil if @item.users == nil
  return @item      
end
```

2nd return is somewhat verbose, you can omit it. You then have either the @item to save or nil. You can make sure in your model, that nil is not saved.

Comment: It's not working. I can create an Item with `Item.create(name:"Car")`.