# How to make a has_many_through association mandatory for one member?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following models :

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities_regions_relationships
  has_many :regions, through: :cities_regions_relationships
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities_regions_relationships
  has_many :cities, through: :cities_regions_relationships
end

class CitiesRegionsRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :region

  validates :city_id, presence: true
  validates :region_id, presence: true
end
```

What I want is to make it impossible to create a city without it linked to a region. However, before attempting that, I have to be able to create a relationship on a city that's not yet saved.

I tried this in the console (with a region already created)

```
c = City.new(name: "Test")
c.cities_region_relationship.build(region_id: Region.first.id)
c.save
```

However, this fails because the relationship doesn't have a city_id (which is normal because I didn't save the city yet, it doesn't have an ID).

I could try other ways, but I will always have the same problem : How do I create a relationship on a new object, not yet saved in database ?

If you have other completely different solutions to my initial problem (Forcing cities to have at least one region), don't hesitate to suggest something entirely different.

Comment: Can a `city` have multiple `regions`?

Comment: @AbM Yes. Otherwise I could have used has_many and belongs_to, but unfortunately my model is not that simple :(

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950008/validate-at-least-one-in-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to build a `cities_region_relationship`. By passing `region_ids` to a new `City` instance, this will create the `cities_region_relationship` for you.

You can try in the console:

```
c = City.new(name: "Test", region_ids: [an array of existing region ids])
c.save
```

for the validation, you can define a new validate method that checks if `self.regions.blank?` like mentioned in the SO post in my comment above.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately : `c.errors`
gives me `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff163ab7870 @base=#<City id: nil, name: "Test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:cities_regions_relationships=>["is invalid"]}>`. As you can see the relationship as no city_id and is invalid.

Comment: I forgot to mention to remove the validations in `CitiesRegionsRelationship` i.e. you do not need `validates :city_id, presence: true` or `validates :region_id, presence: true`. Your validation is only happening in the `City` model to check if an instance has an array of `regions` that is not `blank`